# Use same .env file for server and client (react) app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

**I created a react-create-app and added a backend server to the project:**

```
-- /my-react-app (dotenv already built in automatically)
     -- /src folder
     -- package.json
     -- .env

     -- /backendserver (installed dotenv)
         -- /src folder
         -- package.json
         -- .env
```

So far, I can only get the .env file to work in the **root of each** app.

How can I have only 1 .env file for both.

**Sample .env in react app root:**

```
REACT_APP_DECORATORS=true
REACT_API_PROXY_PORT=4001
.......
.......
```

**Question: How can I create only 1 .env file to hold variables both client side and server side apps use?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works on server side entry file:**

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

console.log('REACT_API_PORT: ' + process.env.REACT_API_PORT); // 4001
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing and configuring the package,
Create a .env file in the root directory of your project.
to ensure it is in the root directory, use the terminal ...
$ cd project
$ touch .env
You can then add all the variables you want included in your .env file

Comment: Can you specify more about "installing and configuring" the package? It seems the user already did that, so what is different from what you are suggesting? Personally, I would refer the user to best practices about how the server should serve the client-side React app, and have the folders reflect that. And then suggest where the new .env should be.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).